# difference between Rotate(angle) and Rotate(angle, px, py) in matrix transformation android

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, imageview

According to official documents of [Android on Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html).

XXRotate(float degrees) --
process the matrix to rotate about (0,0) by the specified number of degrees.

XXRotate(float degrees, float px, float py) -- 
process the matrix to rotate by the specified number of degrees, with a pivot point at (px, py).

- XX set, post or pre as per needed.

for example : XXRotate(90, center_point_x_of_view, center_point_y_of_view)

- Does it take some translate regarding the pivot points while specifying some pivot points ?
- what are the changes in origin coordinates points on views after first rotation?

Comment: the easiest answer is just to run the code with XXRotate and learn how stuff works by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, let's take a square with a width and height of 10.  The upper left corner is at the origin of (0,0) which puts the lower right corner at (10,10).

If we transform that square with `matrix.setRotate(180F)` we would expect that the origin point — being the pivot point — won't move, while the lower right corner is moved to (-10, -10).

Now let's say we transform the square with `matrix.setRotate(180F, 5F, 5F)`.  We have put the pivot point at the center of the square, so we expect that the origin moves to (10, 10) and the lower right corner moves to (0, 0).

So after you look at all the math, it turns out that

```
matrix.setRotate(theta, pivotX, pivotY);
```

is really just a shorter version of

```
matrix.setRotate(theta);
matrix.preTranslate(-pivotX, -pivotY);
matrix.postTranslate(pivotX, pivotY);
```

If you want to know the changes of the points, for the rotation the X changes by the cosine of the angle and the y changes by the sine of the angle.

So simple rotation:

```
float thetaR = theta * Math.PI / 180F; // convert degrees to radians
int x2 = Math.round(x * (float) Math.cos(thetaR));
int y2 = Math.round(y * (float) Math.sin(thetaR));
```

And putting it all together, you have

```
float thetaR = theta * Math.PI / 180F; // convert degrees to radians
int x2 = Math.round((x - pivotX) * (float) Math.cos(thetaR) + pivotX);
int y2 = Math.round((y - pivotY) * (float) Math.sin(thetaR) + pivotY);
```

Comment: Got it..! i tried both combinations...! then what are the changes in origin coordinates points on views after first rotation?

Comment: The rotation of course involves trigonometry.  I updated my answer for the formulas.

Comment: for more clarifying issue on rotate see this-
http://i.imgur.com/Hvic6SL.png and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811559/apply-rotate-transformation-in-old-matrix-android.

Comment: So your other question leads me to your `CropperImageView` class on pastebin.  My question to you is, are all your rotations constrained to 90 degree increments?  In other words, can you only have 90, 180, 270, -90, etc. ?

Comment: Also, are you always rotating from the center of the image, however it happens to be transformed at the moment?

Comment: Hardik, I posted an answer for your other question.  Now I understand. The question you were trying to answer was: how do I figure out where the center of the image is for rotation?  You were taking all the matrix values and trying to work backwards from them.  Much easier to say `matrix.mapRect(rect)` and let the matrix tell you where the image is now.  Cheers